# QQmlListProperty<const QObjectDerived> (notice 'const'): is it feasable somehow?

Tags: qt, qml, constants, qqmllistproperty

I have declared a QML-accessible list property of QObject derived types, and in form without 'const' it works fine:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<QObjectDerived> items READ items NOTIFY updated)
```

But with 'const' modifier:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<const QObjectDerived> items READ items NOTIFY updated)
```

there is unregistered type error on QML side.

Is it feasable somehow to use the second variant?

P.S. I'm using so-called const-propagation, so need to return const-pointers in the list.

Comment: Can you please provide [mcve] or at least the `items()` method? It not so clear why do you want specifically  `const`.

Answer (score -3):

You need to call Test::registerQml() in your main

```
class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<QObjectDerived> items READ items CONSTANT)

public:

    inline QQmlListProperty<QObjectDerived> items()
    {
        return QQmlListProperty<QObjectDerived>(this, data);
    }

    static void registerQml()
    {
        qmlRegisterType<QObjectDerived>("QObjectDerived", 1, 0, "QObjectDerived");
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you understood what the OP wants? He wants to use `QQmlListProperty<const QObjectDerived> ` but you use `QQmlListProperty<QObjectDerived>`.